# Suspicious site hosted on my network - any way to find for sure where/what it is?

Tags: networking, router, webserver, isp

I was trying to see how many devices were on my network using MyLanViewer and [this suspicious IP popped up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH8tE.png)

Apparently it hosts [this website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS5iH.png) (you can [download it here](https://www4.zippyshare.com/v/ZldgM97o/file.html) if you want to look at the source). That's it, only a picture of smoke and an ominously uppercase title.

I tracerouted it to see if the hops have anything useful to say, and [this is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmFwL.png) IPs 1 and 2 are mine, 3-7 belong to my ISP, UPC Romania (owned by Liberty Global IIRC) and then... it returns back to me, as IP 8 is obviously a private IP address(starts with "10.") and 9 is the suspicious website.

Further digging with Nmap [led to this](https://pastebin.com/raw/9XsXfTPP). The server hosting the website is running a Linux derivative (CentOS most likely, according to the Apache web server that's running there). That excludes every single non-mobile device on my network, as my PCs run Windows.

This led me to think there's only two suspects left: my routers. One of them is from TP-Link(don't know the exact model), and provides wireless signal to our guest house 100 meters away, and the other is provided by UPC, a Compal Broadband Networks Connect Box CH7465LG, which is right next to me.

My "network" usually looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9L1F.png), but I disconnected the TP-Link router and the two Windows 7 PCs, leaving us [with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd1Vd.png).

All that's left is this PC, and the Compal router (I disconnected **everything else**). The IP is still accessible, and the traceroute is identical to the one above. Which means the router itself is hosting this website, or my PC is automagically running both Windows and Linux simultaneously.

I'll shutdown this PC and connect my phone to the router to see if the website's still there to narrow it down to the router. Meanwhile, does anyone have any idea what this is? UPC/Liberty Global/etc. customers with a Connect Box, would you mind downloading [MyLanViewer](http://www.mylanviewer.com/index.htm) and searching for similar websites? Server admins, hackers, network specialists, any ideas as to what I could do to find out more about this thing?

Yes, I know it's probably nothing and that I'm too paranoid, but I'm bored :)

EDIT: I shut down the PC, and the site is still there. It's in the router. I'm going to call UPC Romania tomorrow and ask them about this, but meanwhile I'll still dig into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ISP is incompetent and is (incorrectly) routing rfc1918 space from other users (whose device is incorrectly configured) to you. - There is nothing wrong with your network. That 192.168.3 address is outside your Network as demonstrated by the latency if the last hop.

If you can, simply drop traffic originating on your WAN interface with a source address in 192.168.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/8  or 172.16.0.0/18.

A partial workaround if this is not possible - and you want to disallow  access from this range would be to change the netmask of your LAN to 255.255.0.0 on your router. You will most likely find it's set to 255.255.255.0 - which is not a problem in itself, but allows this issue to occur.  (You are actually scanning your LAN and part of the WAN at the moment.